# Appmaker reload value

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a value calculated in window.Sum and I need to display it in label1. Window.Sum is calculated when datasource is filtered and label1 text is set to window.Sum. I log the value of window.Sum and it is correct. How do I force the label1 to display the value everytime the window.Sum is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that the function to calculate the sum you are using is this one:

```
function calculateSum(){

    /* do your stuff right here */
    var sum = x+y;
}
```

All you need to do is to pass the label widget to the function and update the widget text property once you get the sum value, like this:

```
function calculateSum(labelWidget){

    /* do your stuff right here */
    var sum = x+y;
    labelWidget.text = sum;
}
```

Then you just invoke your function passing the labelWidget like this:

```
var labelWidget = app.pathToWhereYourLabelWidgetIsLocated;
calculateSum(labelWidget);
```

Since your question is pretty vague, this is the best I can do to answer your question. Please consult the official documentation for **[widgets data binding](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding)** and **[widgets api](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#Label)** to further understand how to achieve this type of things. Hope it helps!